# How is the state of the entity being persisted between calls to EventSourcingHandlers?

Tags: java, kotlin, persistence, axon

In the [Axon Giftcard demo](https://github.com/AxonIQ/giftcard-demo), there is a `GiftCard` class which is annotated as @Aggregate:

```
@Aggregate
@Profile("command")
public class GiftCard {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;
    private int remainingValue;

    @CommandHandler
    public GiftCard(IssueCmd cmd) {
        log.debug("handling {}", cmd);
        if(cmd.getAmount() <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("amount <= 0");
        apply(new IssuedEvt(cmd.getId(), cmd.getAmount(), cmd.getCurrency()));
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(RedeemCmd cmd) {
        log.debug("handling {}", cmd);
        if(cmd.getAmount() <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("amount <= 0");
        if(cmd.getAmount() > remainingValue) throw new IllegalStateException("amount > remaining value");
        apply(new RedeemedEvt(id, cmd.getAmount()));
    }

...
    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(IssuedEvt evt) {
        log.debug("applying {}", evt);
        id = evt.getId();
        remainingValue = evt.getAmount();
        currency = evt.getCurrency();
        log.debug("new remaining value: {}", remainingValue);
        log.debug("new currency: {}", currency);
    }

   @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(RedeemedEvt evt) {
        log.debug("applying {}", evt);
        remainingValue -= evt.getAmount();
        log.debug("new remaining value: {}", remainingValue);
    }
...
```

The command and event classes are defined in Kotlin code:

```
data class IssueCmd(@TargetAggregateIdentifier val id: String, val amount: Int)
data class IssuedEvt(val id: String, val amount: Int)
data class RedeemCmd(@TargetAggregateIdentifier val id: String, val amount: Int)
data class RedeemedEvt(val id: String, val amount: Int)
```

Let's say the following two commands are put on the command bus:

```
Command #     Command Class   id          amount
---------     -------------   -------     -------------
1             IssueCmd        QP34        123.45
2             RedeemCmd       QP34        38.10
```

When processing the first command, the CommandHandler (CH) for `IssueCmd` will put an `IssuedEvt` object on the event bus. The event will be processed by the EventSourcingHandler (ESH) for the `IssuedEvt`. We'll then have an instance of `GiftCard` with `id` set to "*QP34*" and `remainingValue` set to *123.45*.

When processing the second command, the CH for `RedeemCmd` will put a `RedeemedEvt` object on the event bus. The event will be processed by the ESH for the `RedeeemedEvt`. We'll then have an instance of `GiftCard` with `id` set to "*QP34*" and `remainingValue` set to *85.35*.

**QUESTION: After each event is handled by its designated ESH, how and where does the resulting object instance persist?**

Previously, the answer I've heard is: it really doesn't. All that persists are the event objects, and those are kept in Axon's event store. When an object's current state is needed, Axon tells the command model to initiate an instance of the `GiftCard` class and events are applied to it from the earliest to the latest. This is the definition of Event Sourcing.

But, when Event Sourcing, after the `IssuedEvt` is processed, the *123.45* in `remainingValue` has to be persisted somewhere in order for the ESH for the `RedeemedEvt` to have the correct value for its subtraction operation.

**How and where is the object state persisted between calls to the ESHs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework internally instantiates an `AnnotatedAggregate` when you retrieve an `Aggregate` instance from the `Repository`.

The `AnnotatedAggregate` class implements the `Aggregate`, which the `Repository` interface enforces to be the return type on a `load(String)` operation.

As you're talking about Event Sourcing, the `Repository` implementation being used is the `EventSourcingRepository`, which on a `load(String)` returns a `EventSourcedAggregate` instance (this is an implementation of the `AnnotatedAggregate`.

The `Aggregate` interface, `AnnotatedAggregate` implementation of that interface and the `EventSourcedAggregate` again implementing that, define a generic.

This generic is *your* Aggregate implementation.

When you are Event Sourcing an Aggregate through the `EventSourcingRepository`, *your* Aggregate instance is kept **in memory** in the `AnnotatedAggregate` under the `private T aggregateRoot` global field.

This `aggregateRoot` is updated by the `EventSourcingRepository`, which initializes the state of your `EventSourcedAggregate` by giving it a stream of `EventMessages`.

By the way, why are you interested in this exact bit, @JonathanM?

For reference, here are the GitHub links to the classes:

1. [`Aggregate`](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/31fe8a7eae/modelling/src/main/java/org/axonframework/modelling/command/Aggregate.java)
2. [`AnnotatedAggregate`](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/31fe8a7eae7bf019b7e7e4fc10d5ee2230e0b56b/modelling/src/main/java/org/axonframework/modelling/command/inspection/AnnotatedAggregate.java)
3. [`EventSourcedAggregate`](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/31fe8a7eae/eventsourcing/src/main/java/org/axonframework/eventsourcing/EventSourcedAggregate.java)
4. [`Repository`](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/31fe8a7eae/modelling/src/main/java/org/axonframework/modelling/command/Repository.java)
5. [`EventSourcingRepository`](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/31fe8a7eae/eventsourcing/src/main/java/org/axonframework/eventsourcing/EventSourcingRepository.java)

Comment: Good answer that I'm still trying to digest. :) Asking because, unlike the query model, the command model never *appears* to persist an instance anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! 
And understandable you're interested in some background regarding the inner workings; it's not always to pleasing to work with a black box of course.